# Initializing private struct variable inside main

Tags: c++

I want to initialize struct member variable(privately, I do not want to have a global struct, it will be easy but not so good). I have searched for it in StackOverflow but I have not found any useful solution for this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

class linked_list
{
private:
    node internal;
public:
    linked_list()
    {
    }
    linked_list(const linked_list &);

    void push(node *head, int m_data);
    void printList(node *head);
    void swap(node *first, int x, int y);
};

void linked_list::push(node *head, int m_data)
{
    node *newNode=new node;
    newNode->data=m_data;
    newNode->next=head;
    head=newNode;
}

void linked_list::printList(node *head)
{
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<head->data<<" ";
        head=head->next;
    }
}

void linked_list::swap(node *head, int x, int y)
{
    if(x==y){ return;}
    node *prevX=NULL;
    node *currentX=head;
    while(currentX!=NULL && currentX->data!=x)
    {
        prevX=currentX;
        currentX=currentX->next;
    }

    node *prevY=NULL;
    node *currentY=head;
    while(currentY!=NULL && currentY->data!=y)
    {
        prevY=currentY;
        currentY=currentY->next;
    }
    if(currentX==NULL || currentY==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(prevX!=NULL)
    {
        prevX->next=currentY;
    }
    else
    {
        head=prevX;
    }
    if(prevY!=NULL)
    {
        prevY->next=currentX;
    }
    else
    {
        head=prevY;
    }
    node *temp=new node;
    temp=currentY->next;
    currentY->next=currentX->next;
    currentX->next=temp;
}

int main()
{
    linked_list list;
    list.internal.head = NULL;

    /* The constructed linked list is:
     1->2->3->4->5->6->7 */

    list.push(&head, 7);
    list.push(&head, 6);
    list.push(&head, 5);
    list.push(&head, 4);
    list.push(&head, 3);
    list.push(&head, 2);
    list.push(&head, 1);

    printf("\n Linked list before calling swapNodes() ");
    list.printList(&head);

    list.swap(&head, 4, 3);

   list.printList(&head);
    return 0;
}
```

I want this program to print given swapped elements linked list.

Error: node linked_list::internal’ is private

Comment: You'd initialize `list.internal` in your constructors.

Comment: `list.internal.head = NULL;` should not be done in main anyways. As @frslm said do that in your constructor.

Comment: You can't access it, it's in `private` scope. What's actually unclear about that error message?

Comment: main shouldn't know anything about "internal" inside list.  It should only use the public interface that list provides.  The list class knows about its internals, and so it's the list class's job to initialize it.  That is why classes have constructors...

Comment: Thank you very much for all answers, now I understand.

Comment: when I initialize it in the constructor and then I call the class object in main how that constructor passes the value of for example node *head=NULL to the function that is called inside main

Comment: You shouldn't call your `linked_list` variable `list` since that is also a container object in the standard template library.

Comment: You should not take head as a parameter. `node internal;` probably should be renamed to `node head;`

Comment: I did like that. Thanks

Comment: when I call linked list constructor,  I must declare head node in main also to initialize it with NULL when calling the constructor, yes?

Comment: ***when I call linked list constructor, I must declare head node in main also to initialize it with NULL when calling the constructor, yes?*** No. main should not even know there is a head node. That is part of removing the head node parameter from your member functions.